# How to make wamp/apache to use htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp64

I forked a working php project from github to create some json files to it, but i can't test it because js and css won't load, i have never used php in my life, so i followed what the install guide said.

1. `composer install`
2. edit .env
3. `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed -vvv`

testing vendor/bin/phpunit

This was the guide.

What i did step by step.

1. installed wamp64
2. cloned the repo into www
3. installed composer
4. ran the `composer install` command on the right folder
5. created virtual host for the folder with wamps add a virtual host option, named targygraf.test
6. created a db with phpmyadmin and set pw
7. edited the .env file to targygraf.test and to use the db and pw i created
8. ran `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed -vvv`

It did what it should i suppose because the database built up, and i was able to access the page with the server.php file, except that css and js didn't load.
Checked with the inspector and they were linked like this `http://targygraf.test/server.php/assets/js/targygraf.js`, i have visited a TON of forums about the problem, every single one said that i have to turn `rewite_module` on and set `AlloweOverride` to All so i did. But still nothing, and as i said earlier, the app was working on another pc and is working online right now, so i'm guessing i did something wrong.

This is the original github link: https://github.com/valentinxxx/targygraf

Edit1: corrected step 5 and 7, added original link

Comment: Can you show us your Virtual Host definition.

Comment: i used wamps add a virtual host option, with the name targygraf.test and the path pointing to the folder containing the project.
Also edit: in the .env file the app_domain was set to this address

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to resolve this problem

- reinstalled wamp and composer
- forked a clean repo of the project
- ran `composer install`
- set phpmyadmin pw
- created mysql table
- created virtual host, this time pointing to `[project_folder]\public` instead of `[project_folder]` (This is the important part as with pointing to `[project folder]` the page will load but without css, but with the address pointing to `[project_folder]\public` the page works perfectly)
- ran `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed -vvv`

Answer (score 0):

this is a Laravel project, so if it's your first time with php, it becomes a little more complicated. 
In a few words:

1. laravel uses the routes at /routes/web.php, so: it's using: `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex')->name('index');` for the home
2. `/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController@getIndex` calls `layouts.index` view .
3. this view uses `/resources/views/template.blade.php`. You can check your css and js there.

You can replace `{{ url('assets/css/style.css') }}` for `'/assets/css/style.css'` and see if this way the browser finds the file.

Anyway, there are other possible problems, keep in mind your Apache server should open "[project_folder]/public"

Comment: hi, i tried your solution, sadly, the problem is still there, even though i tied it with different browsers

Comment: tried a couple more things, and was able fix the problem, thanks the tip to point the apache server to public